# Fixing problems with yum, urllib2, and missing dependencies?

Tags: python, centos5, yum, dependencies, libraries

I've been trying to resolve the following problem with yum / python's urllib2:

```
[root@...]# yum
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 4, in ?
    import yum
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 51, in ?
    import config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/config.py", line 27, in ?
    from parser import ConfigPreProcessor
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/parser.py", line 3, in ?
    import urlgrabber
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/urlgrabber/__init__.py", line 53, in ?
    from grabber import urlgrab, urlopen, urlread
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 412, in ?
    import keepalive
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/urlgrabber/keepalive.py", line 339, in ?
    class HTTPSHandler(KeepAliveHandler, urllib2.HTTPSHandler):

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSHandler'
```

I tried updating python to see if it would fix the library:

`rpm -Uvh python-2.4.3-44.el5.x86_64.rpm`

But it didn't change anything after a reboot, so I decided to see what's going wrong:

```
prelink -all
rpm -Va
```

This results in a LOT of unsatisfied dependencies:

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for gnome-panel-2.16.1-7.el5.i386: libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
Unsatisfied dependencies for gtkhtml3-3.16.3-1.el5.i386: libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
Unsatisfied dependencies for libgnomeui-2.16.0-5.el5.i386: libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
...
missing     /lib/libz.so.1
missing     /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
missing     /usr/lib/libz.so.1
missing     /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
Unsatisfied dependencies for Nessus-4.4.0-es4.i386: libcrypto.so.4, libssl.so.4
...
```

I'm unsure what provides `libpangocairo-1.0.so.0`, and neither is `rpm`, so I started by checking what provides `libz.so.1` and attempting to update it:

```
[root@...]# rpm -q --whatprovides libz.so.1
zlib-1.2.3-4.el5.i386

[root@...]# rpm -Uvh --force zlib-1.2.3-4.el5.i386.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:zlib                   ########################################### [100%]
```

After updating, `libz.so.1` and `libz.so.1.2.3` still do not exist under `/usr` or `/usr/lib`, and running `rpm -Va` still reports the files as missing.

When I try to `find / -name 'libz.so.1`, the only results are in `/lib64` and `/usr/lib64`, which I believe are coming from the `x86_64` version of the package that is also installed.

How should I proceed?

Comment: aparently you have a mess here, your CentOS is 32 bits or 64 bits ?

Comment: @BlackHand: Yes, it's very much a mess. CentOS is 64-bit, but some installed packages require 32-bit libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today on a brand new CentOS 5.11 VM. I know the OS is no longer "officially" supported, but... customers.

In my case, I had updated openssl to 1.0.2m, from the default openssl-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.4. I thought I had fixed the (re)-creation of those compatibility links in my spec file but apparently, the ordering of rpm scriptlets has bitten me, yet again.

There are two symlinks in /lib that I had to recreate:

```
# ln -s /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /lib/libcrypto.so.6
# ln -s /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 /lib/libssl.so.6
```

After that, all was peachy.